Are Dogs OK with UFH?
We may get UFH (Under Floor Heating) installed, do we need a unheated part of the floor for our cockapoo?

Health or comfort wise?

@JourneymanGeek both

If you can comfortably stand barefoot on the heated floor, other mammals will generally be comfortable with it.

I'd say it's safe to assume there are no real implications for a dog (or cat) here.
Our cat always used to sleep right next to the heated oven (easily 30°C or more in winter) and never had any issues. Even one of our Huskies enjoys doing so now and then.
Just ensure the pet has ways to get away from the heated surface, e.g. by also offering some elevated or isolated alternative sleeping position it a room with it being disabled.
Also make sure there's not a constant switching between hot and cold (e.g. open windows or going outside). Just like with humans.
Otherwise I'd say it won't be that different than the floor being heated by the sun in summer.
